# Export vector layer in DXF with systematically metrical system unit?

Tags: qgis, gdal, export, dxf, autocad

As said on this page https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/dxf.html,

> GDAL writes DXF files with measurement units set to “Imperial -
>   Inches”. If you need to change the units, edit the $MEASUREMENT and
>   $INSUNITS variables in the header template

$MEASUREMENT and $INSUNITS are the variables *in Autocad* in order to choose between an imperial and a metric system.

As I never use the imperial system, **is it possible to configure Qgis in order to systematically export vector layers in DXF format with a metric system?** I precise that my Qgis is configured with the language, numbers, date and currency formats from the US).

I totally agree with the fact that this is not a big problem, but I have the feeling to lose so much time everyday just to change the unity from the imperial to the metric system in Autocad.

I think it would be interesting in the future to let that choice to the user in the "Save Vector Layer as ..." window...

Comment: Did you try "Project -> Export to DXF"?

Comment: Yes, the problem is the same.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out what meant "edit the $MEASUREMENT and $INSUNITS variables in the header template".

The header template is located here: C:\OSGeo4W\apps\gdal\share\gdal\header.dxf

This is an ASCII DXF file that contains the variables $MEASUREMENT and $INSUNITS. Originally, these variables are :

```
$MEASUREMENT
    70
         0
      9
```

and

```
$INSUNITS
 70
     1
  9
```

which correspond to the imperial units. According to the documentation for [$MEASUREMENT](https://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2019/ENU/?guid=GUID-1D074C55-0B63-482E-8A37-A52AC0C7C8FE) and [$INSUNITS](https://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2021/ENU/?guid=GUID-A58A87BB-482B-4042-A00A-EEF55A2B4FD8) and with the help of a text editor, I changed the parameters to :

```
$MEASUREMENT
 70
     1
  9
```

and

```
$INSUNITS
 70
     6
  9
```

Unfortunately, this solution only works for data exported layer by layer (and not by Project>Import/Export>Export Project to DXF...).

If someone has an idea about it, I'll take it.